# Render events on Full calendar using JSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to render events on Full calendar js by building  a JSON object and pass it to the Event handler on Full Calendar, code goes like this:

```
$('#dailyPaymentsModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var matrixId = button.data('id');
  var matrixprice = button.data('price');
  var qualifiedDate = button.data('qdate');
  var qDate = new Date(qualifiedDate);
  var tomorrow = new Date(qualifiedDate);
  var endDate = new Date(qualifiedDate);
  endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 14);
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var nextDay = qDate;
  var myObject = new Object();
  var myarray = [];
  var dailybonus = matrixprice * 0.03;
  while (nextDay <= endDate) {
    myObject.title = 'Daily Bonus';
    myObject.start = nextday;
    myObject.description = dailybonus;
    myarray.push(myObject);
    nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
  }
  var myString = JSON.stringify(myarray);
  alert(myString);
  var calendar = $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar({
    events: myString,
    displayEventTime: false,
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.find('.fc-title').text(event.title);
    }
  });
})
```

I get a JSON array in myString, but when passed to events on Full calendar, it does not render any event.

Comment: why do you stringify the array?  this example has an array - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-array

Comment: I used var myString = JSON.stringify(myarray);

Comment: fullCalendar doesn't want JSON, it wants an actual array of objects. If you don't understand the difference between JSON and a JavaScript object/array literal, it's basically this: JSON is text, i.e. a _string_. It's a _representation_ of an object which is useful when storing data or transmitting it across the internet. It's **not** an actual object or array which can be used by JavaScript. It just happens to have a syntax which is similar to the syntax you use in JavaScript when you hard-code objects in your code. But to actually use JSON in a program, you have to decode it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `JSON.stringify(myarray);` just remove that line and use `myarray` in events.

```
// var myString = JSON.stringify(myarray);
// alert(myString);
var calendar = $('#fcalendar').fullCalendar({
   events: myarray,
   displayEventTime: false,
   eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.find('.fc-title').text(event.title);
   }
});
```

**Note**
Fullcalendar has a very good demo that you can simply use them to build yours. here is a demo of event data that you can use. https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/YzzdxWg?editors=0010